# How to reshape Test dataframe so that dimension is same as used in Training and Prediction works?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, predict, one-hot-encoding

Need to know what changes need to be done so that test data will have same level of encoded column as training for prediction to work..it now fails with dimension error.

Checked in forums for similar query..

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# initialize list of lists 
data = [[1001, 10,'Male',38], [2001, 15,'Male',50], [2004, 12,'FeMale',40]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender','Weight']) 

#Define y , X, test and train

y=df['Weight']
X=df[['StudentId','Age','Gender']] 
# One-hot encode the data using pandas get_dummies
X = pd.get_dummies(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=66)

X_test.head()
----
StudentId   Age Gender_FeMale   Gender_Male
1   2001    15  0   1
---
# linear regression model creation
lm_model = LinearRegression()
lm_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

# predictions
lm_model.predict(X_test)

---works fine till now..--
When we now create a single test record and test it fails as the dimension mismatch happens,,, Does one have to manually add another encoded dimension or some clean approach is there...please advice..

sample_testdata=[[4001, 10,'FeMale']]
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
sample_testDF= pd.DataFrame(sample_testdata, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender']) 

sample_testDF_encoded=pd.get_dummies(sample_testDF)
-----
    StudentId   Age Gender_FeMale
0   4001    10  1

---

lm_model.predict(sample_testDF_encoded)

--Error----

ValueError: shapes (1,3) and (4,) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

Prediction on a single test record fails as get_dummies produce one col...

Comment: you would need to pass a `sample_testdata` with multiple records which should include atleast one record per category(male/ female) for `get_dummies` to work.

Comment: Thanks for the time. That's a hack. sample_testdata is fed by a user . I don't want to force the user to write all possible levels of categorical values used in training.Any other thoughts..

Comment: Added an alternative answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a better user experience, you can add multiple categories and covert it into [pandas categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical) variable after users input and before using one hot encode/ get_dummies. Something like:

```
# Sample input from user
sample_testdata = [[4001, 10,'FeMale']]
sample_testDF = pd.DataFrame(sample_testdata, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender'])

# Add categories and convert to categorical variable
sample_testDF['Gender'] = pd.Categorical(sample_testDF['Gender'], 
                                         categories = ["Male", "FeMale"])

# Create dummies and index columns based on your X_test/ X_train
sample_testDF_dum = pd.get_dummies(sample_testDF)[X_test.columns]
sample_testDF_dum

#    StudentId  Age Gender_FeMale   Gender_Male
# 0       4001  10  1               0
```

Comment: Works fine in case of drop_first = False. But if you set drop_first = True then the outcomes is quite unpredictable. For instance, I have a gender column containing 3 categories i.e. Male, Female, Unknown. 

with pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True) on X_train, it generates the following columns
Gender_male  | Gender_Unknown

But using the same technique on X_test, it generates the following 2 columns: Gender_Female  |  Gender_Unknown

Train has a Male column encoded but Test data has a Female column encoded (based on the data available in test).

Answer (score 1):

```
print(X_train.columns)
```

this produces:

```
Index(['StudentId', 'Age', 'Gender_FeMale', 'Gender_Male'], dtype='object')

print(sample_testDF_encoded.columns)
```

this produces:

```
Index(['StudentId', 'Age', 'Gender_FeMale'], dtype='object')
```

So, the problem is your one hot encoder makes two columns for gender in main data where Gender value is either Male or FeMale (it encodes Gender_FeMale to 1 if your data contains female, it encodes Gender_Male to 1 if your data contains male)
But your sample_testDF contains only one value that is FeMale. So, one hot encoder doesn't make 2 columns this time for Gender. So this is the miss match

So your test data should look like:

```
sample_testdata=[[4001, 10,1, 0]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
sample_testDF= pd.DataFrame(sample_testdata, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender_FeMale', 'Gender_Male'])
```

Changing these tow line will remove error and gave you the prediction result

As you said in comment sample data is inputted by user, so you have to convert it as I replied in that comment. You can create a converted data list than make Dataframe with that converted list:

```
sample_testdata= [[4001, 10,'FeMale']]

convertedDataList = []
for data in sample_testdata:
    if data[2] == 'FeMale':
        data[2] = 1
        data.append(0)
    else:
        data[2] = 0
        data.append(1) 
    convertedDataList.append(data)


# Create the pandas DataFrame  using convertedDataList
sample_testDF= pd.DataFrame(convertedDataList, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender_FeMale', 'Gender_Male'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the time. That's a hack. sample_testdata is fed by a user . I don't want to force the user to write all possible levels of categorical values used in training.Any other thoughts..

Comment: don't need to force a user to do anything, if user input is [4001, 10,'FeMale'] then convert it to [4001, 10,1, 0] , if user input is [4001, 10,'Male'] then convert it to  [4001, 10,0, 1]

Comment: I have edited my answer and added how you can convert user input to the needed format for the regression model

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because

```
sample_testdata=[[4001, 10,'FeMale']]
sample_testDF= pd.DataFrame(sample_testdata, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender']) 
sample_testDF_encoded=pd.get_dummies(sample_testDF)
gives the output :
 StudentId     Age    Gender_FeMale
    4001        10      1
```

but your test case needs to have one more column Gender_Male as your trainig dataset has Gender_Male column so this column gives column mismatch here
so you need to perform either of the option:

```
sample_testdata=[[4001, 10,'FeMale'],[4001, 10,'Male']]
OR
sample_testDF= pd.DataFrame(sample_testdata, columns = ['StudentId', 'Age','Gender_FeMale', 'Gender_Male'])
```

this one gives me the following output:

```
sample_testdata=[[4001, 10,'FeMale'],[4001, 10,'Male']]
lm_model.predict(sample_testDF_encoded)
array([43.98202214, 43.98201816])
```

Comment: Thanks for the time. That's a hack. sample_testdata is fed by a user . I don't want to force the user to write all possible levels of categorical values used in training.Any other thoughts..